# Excel does not compute formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with simple formulas like `=SUM(F15+F21+F27+F33+F39+F45+F51+F57+F63+F69+F75+F81+F87)`. But for some reason those formulas are not computed without entering in cell formula and pressing enter. I found few things which could be the problem but none of them help:

- "Show formulas" button clicked
- Cell formatting as Text instead of Number
- Circular references
- Calculation options turned to manually

Any other idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm assuming the data in each of these fields are of numeric data-type?

Comment: Your calculations are set to manual.  Hit F9 to calculate or turn the Calculation to automatic in the options

Comment: @jimmy8ball yes everything is numeric.

Comment: Try the shortcut "ctrl + ~" to turn off showing the functions

Comment: Please see [Cells not updating automatically](https://superuser.com/q/836324) topic.

Comment: @ScottCraner the calculation is turned to automatic. I add this to the list.

Comment: Are all of the formulas in the sheet just showing text?

Comment: @Jarom no it's not showing text but always 0 whereas I expect another result.

Comment: Very unlikely, but custom number format?  If you have, for example, a custom number format of `36` all cells will show that no matter what number you type in.  The sum of those values will copy the format and show `36` as well.  As I said... very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you should have + in a sum function.  Remove the Sum and just add them like this `=F15+F21+F27+F33+F39+F45+F51+F57+F63+F69+F75+F81+F87`.

Comment: Completely disagree with this - if anything it should be `=SUM(F15,F21,F27,F33,F39,F45,F51,F57,F63,F69,F75,F81,F87)`.  Use `Evaluate Formula` with the original formula, and your formula.  Assuming you have 1, 2, 3, 4.... in the cell references it will calculate as `F15=1`, `F21=2`, `1+2=3`, `F27=3`, `3+3=6`, `F33=4`, `6+4=10`,.... in total 25 clicks of `Evaluate Formula`.  With commas - `=SUM(F15,F21,F27,F33,F39,F45,F51,F57,F63,F69,F75,F81,F87) = 36`... one click of `Evaluate Formula`.  If this is a reflection of how Excel does it... commas are much faster.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Interesting, I am not a performance guru so I am not sure how these formulas are evaluated but what you say does make sense.

Comment: Me neither.  I just noticed it a few years ago while figuring out how a formula worked.  You can find the `Evaluate Formula` button on the `Formulas` ribbon under `Formula Auditing`.

Answer (score 2):

Click the File tab, click Options, and then click the Formulas category. Do one of the following: To recalculate all dependent formulas every time you make a change to a value, formula, or name, in the Calculation options section, under Workbook Calculation, click Automatic.

Comment: In which case try @Darren Bartrup-Cook's comment on Craig Howell's answer
=SUM(F15,F21,F27,F33,F39,F45,F51,F57,F63,F69,F75,F81,F87)